# Add Eth0 but there is LO and ENS160

Tags: ubuntu, networking, ethernet

I want to add static Ip to ubunto server , but I can not .
when I use " ip addr" :
[image]

and there is no "network" service .
how can I setup static IP ?
I am beginner at linux, please guide me A-Z
thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

You're probably trying to follow obsolete instructions.

`ens160` is a [new-style network device name](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/PredictableNetworkInterfaceNames/), while `eth0`is old-style.

Also, modern Ubuntu uses [`netplan` to configure network settings](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/network-configuration.html): you should create (or edit, if one already exists) a simple `*.yaml` file describing your desired network configuration in `/etc/netplan/` directory, and then run `sudo netplan apply` to make it take effect.

For example, to set IP address 10.10.10.2 with netmask 255.255.255.0 (i.e. prefix /24), default gateway 10.10.10.1, DNS server 10.10.10.1 and 1.1.1.1 with default DNS search domains `mydomain.example` and `otherdomain.example`, you would write this into e.g. `/etc/netplan/99_config.yaml`:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    ens160:
      addresses:
        - 10.10.10.2/24
      gateway4: 10.10.10.1
      nameservers:
          search: [mydomain.example, otherdomain.example]
          addresses: [10.10.10.1, 1.1.1.1]
```

Note that in YAML, correct indentation is an important part of the syntax.